# how come my code isn't recognizing input?

Tags: java

I want this code to recognize the users input ex: `2+3`
and make it `5`
or if user inputs `4*3` give me `12`
how do i modify my code?

I am currently getting

Enter expression: `3+3`

and then it gave me space to enter two more inputs like this which shouldn't be allowed
3_#
3&3

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "3+3"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:766)
at Calculator.main(Calculator.java:13)
```

----jGRAS

before giving me that error^^^
How can I get it to recognize the input operator and go to the calculator1 method and process the basic arithmetic?

thank you in advance for any advice.
here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Calculator {
     public static void main(String[] args) {      


         Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

         System.out.print("Enter expression: ");   
         String d = kb.next();
         String f = kb.next();
         String e = kb.next();
         int a = (Integer.valueOf(d));
         int b = (Integer.valueOf(e));
         char c = f.charAt(0);
         calculator1(a, b, c);


     }
     public static int calculator1(int a, int b, char c)  {

         int fault = Integer.parseInt("Please Check Your Expression.");

         if("+".equals(c)) 
             System.out.print(a+b);
         else if ("-".equals(c)) 
             System.out.print(a-b);
         else if ("*".equals(c))  
             System.out.print(a*b);
         else if ("/".equals(c)) 
             System.out.print(a/b);
         return fault;
     }
}
```

Comment: `Integer.parseInt("Please Check Your Expression.");` will fail no matter what... You have to send a string representation of an **integer** for it to work... Like `Integer.parseInt("50");`

Comment: oh ok, do you have any tips on how i can return the string ? I have tried multiple things but can't get anything to work in the return statement.

Comment: You can't return a `String` from a method whose return type is `int`... Your out of luck..:(.. My suggestion would be to print the String from your method and return a default int value or you have to redesign your method...

Comment: Does my answer not work?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to compare between a `String` and a `char`. You're doing:

```
if("+".equals(c))
    ....
```

It should be:

```
if('+' == c)
    ....
```

Also, try using `Integer.parseInt()` instead like the following:

```
 int a = (Integer.parseInt(d));
```

Lastly, you can't `parseInt` a full sentence like `"Please Check Your Expression."`. `Integer.parseInt` is supposed to parse the string to find a match numeric value.

So if you were to execute `Integer.parseInt("5")`, it will return an `int` of `5`.

It looks like you're program is just trying to print out the result. If that's the case, I would change the return type your `calculator1` method from `int` to `void` and remove `return fault;` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

There's a better way to do this.

With JDK1.6, you can use the built-in Javascript engine to convert Strings to mathematical expressions and evaluate the value. Have a look at the example below, you can pass in the String values you get from the user to something like this.

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("Welcome to my calculator. Enter quit to exit");

        while(true) {

            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter a mathematical expression: ");
            String expression = input.next();

            if(expression.equals("quit")) {

                System.out.println("Thank you for using my calculator. Good bye!"); 
                System.exit(0);
            }

            ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
            ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
            System.out.println("Solution is : " + engine.eval(expression));
        }
    }
}
```